# How to ignore not existing bean if some other bean depends on it?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I use Flyway in my application and it is configured as Spring bean, which performs migration as init-method([example configuration can be found here in the bottom](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/)). Of course migration should be performed before any app's interaction with database.
That's why my datasource bean **depend on** Flyway bean. But i create Flyway bean conditionally using `@Profile`, because i do not want to create it using the same app's context in integration tests.

The problem is that when i use test profile which does not create Flyway bean, datasource instantiation fails with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, because it `depends-on="flyway"` which is not created with current profile. Can i somehow make spring to ignore this `depends-on` dependency, if related bean does not exist? If no, what is the way to decouple Flyway bean from context when i use it under test profile?

Comment: should it be possible for you to create a sessionFactory bean which does not have value depends-on ?

Comment: @kuhajeyan it is possible, but as i understand this trick does not allow application to do something with database while performing migrations which take too much time. That's why `depends-on` is used.